# Can I Transform a XSLT into XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

In my recent project I have a situation where I need to transform an XSLt into XML- Can I do this and how is that possible?

Comment: xslt is already xml

Comment: I have to convert that  XSLT into XML, how can I do this?

Comment: You **don't need** to convert anything.

Comment: You recite the words "presto! change-o! let this XSLT stylesheet be an XML document!"  And if what you have really is an XSLT stylesheet, lo and behold, after your spell it will be a well-formed XML document.  (Also before your spell, but why pick at nits?)

Answer (score 0):

XSLT (eXtensible Stylesheet Language Transformation) **is** XML (eXtensible Markup Language), it is used to Transform other XML to basically any type of text, often more XML.

most of the time, some data in an xml document is transformed by applying a transformation using an xslt document to generate output.

For example; One could have a list of books in an xml data file suitable for computer software to consume and an xslt stylesheet that is able to transform that list of books to an html (or xhtml, or...) document that is more suitable for human consumption.

here is some example code that works with xslt for good measure:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

namespace XSLTProcessorTool
{
    use DOMDocument;
    use XSLTProcessor;

    /**
     * Class Processor: Process an xml file according to a stylesheet
     */
    class Program
    {
        static function main(array $args)
        {
            if(count($args) >= 3)
            {

                /** @noinspection PhpUnusedLocalVariableInspection Intentionally ignoring the first element here */
                $programFile = array_shift($args);
                $xmlFile = array_shift($args);
                $xslFile = array_shift($args);

                $xml = new DOMDocument();
                if (false != ($xml->load($xmlFile)))
                {
                    $xsl = new DOMDocument();
                    if (false != ($xsl->load($xslFile)))
                    {
                        $transformer = new XSLTProcessor();
                        $transformer->importStylesheet($xsl);
                        $result = $transformer->transformToXml($xml);

                        fputs(STDOUT, $result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self::reportFatalError(sprintf('Unable to read XSL from %s', $xslFile));
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    self::reportFatalError(sprintf('Unable to read XML from %s', $xmlFile));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                self::reportFatalError('Need at 2 parameters representing an xml file and the xsl sheet to transform it with.');
            }
        }

        /**
         * Log an error message and exit.
         * 
         * @param $message
         */
        private static function reportFatalError($message)
        {
            fputs(STDERR, $message);
            die(1);
        }
    }

    // usage: php -q xslt.php data.xml stylesheet.xslt > output.xml

    /** @var $argv array containing commandline arguments */
    Program::main($argv);
}

#EOF
```

This is a commandline tool that takes two arguments; a path to an xml data file and a path to an xslt file. the output is dumped to stdout (the console you started it from, or redirected to a file etc.)